# Processing - Stop image from disappearing when selecting another

Tags: java, processing

I am able to select an image file from my computer using the 't' key in the `keyPressed()` function and display it on the screen, but when I press the 't' key again to select another image, the previous image disappears.

I would like my program to not have the image disappear when selecting and displaying another.

I would also like to have `background()` inside `draw()` as the image will leave trails of images whenever I move it with the mouse.

My code

```java
PImage img;
int imgX, imgY;
int mX, mY;
String path ="";

void setup() {
    size(1000, 800);
}

void draw() {
    background(204);
    if(mousePressed){ // is the mousebutton being held?
        imgX = mouseX-mX;
        imgY = mouseY-mY;
    }
    if (img != null) {
        image(img, imgX, imgY);
    }
    text("Press 't' to load an image", 40, 100);
}

void handleImage(File selection) {
    if (selection== null) {
        println ("nono");
    } 
    else {
        path = selection.getAbsolutePath();
        img = loadImage(path);
    }
}

void mousePressed()
{
    // set variables for holding mouseposition offset
    // to the image
    mX = mouseX-imgX;
    mY = mouseY-imgY;
}

void keyPressed() {
    if(key == 't') {
        img = null;
        selectInput("select an image", "handleImage");
    }
}
```

Comment: The image is not disappearing. The image just changes, because you have just 1 image (`img`). The entire scene is redrawn in every frame so you can just see the "current" image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image is not disappearing. The image just changes, because you have just 1 image (`img`). The entire scene is redrawn in every frame so you can just see the "current" image.

Create a class `MyImage`, which can draw an image and change the position of an image:

```java
class MyImage {
    PImage img;
    int x, y;

    MyImage(PImage img, int x, int y) {
        this.img = img;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    void changePosition(int dx, int dy) {
        this.x += dx;
        this.y += dy;
    }

    void draw() {
        image(img, x, y);
    }
}
```

Use an [`ArrayList`](https://processing.org/reference/ArrayList.html) to manage multiple images:

```java
ArrayList<MyImage> images = new ArrayList<MyImage>();
```

Add a new image when <kbd>t</kbd> is pressed:

```java
String path = selection.getAbsolutePath();
PImage image = loadImage(path);
images.add(new MyImage(image, 0, 0));
```

Draw all the images  in a loop

```java
for (int i = 0; i < images.size(); i++) {
    MyImage img = images.get(i);
    img.draw();
}
```

Use the [`mouseDragged()`](https://processing.org/reference/mouseDragged_.html) event call back to drag the last image in the list:

```java
void mouseDragged() {
    if (images.size() > 0) {
        images.get(images.size()-1).changePosition(mouseX-pmouseX, mouseY-pmouseY);
    }
}
```

See the example:

[image]

```java
class MyImage {
    PImage img;
    int x, y;

    MyImage(PImage img, int x, int y) {
        this.img = img;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    void changePosition(int dx, int dy) {
        this.x += dx;
        this.y += dy;
    }

    void draw() {
        image(img, x, y);
    }
}

ArrayList<MyImage> images = new ArrayList<MyImage>();

void setup() {
    size(1000, 800);
}

void draw() {
    background(204);
    for (int i = 0; i < images.size(); i++) {
        MyImage img = images.get(i);
        img.draw();
    }
    text("Press 't' to load an image", 40, 100);
}

void handleImage(File selection) {
    if (selection == null) {
        println ("nono");
    } 
    else {
        String path = selection.getAbsolutePath();
        PImage image = loadImage(path);
        images.add(new MyImage(image, 0, 0));
    }
}

void mouseDragged() {
    if (images.size() > 0) {
        images.get(images.size()-1).changePosition(mouseX-pmouseX, mouseY-pmouseY);
    }
}

void keyPressed() {
    if(key == 't') {
        selectInput("select an image", "handleImage");
    }
}
```

Comment: @Rabbid76 very nicely explained answer (+1)! (silly question: what do you use to screen record gifs ?)

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza Thank you. I use [ScrrenToGif](https://www.screentogif.com/). It's marvelous easy, but it's just for windows os.